# Android Update TextView from activity on the run

Tags: textview

So, I'm tired of trying to find a solution for this. I'm self-learning Java, so, my knowledge is kind of limited....

There are a lot of questions of how to update a TextView text in a fragment from the activity, but non of them have work for me.

I got the next method in my fragment, that is inside a pager:

```
static TextView tv_db_stat;    

public static Stored_Fragment newInstance(String db_stat){
        Stored_Fragment fragment = new Stored_Fragment();
        args.putString(ARG_DB_STAT,db_stat);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        tv_db_stat.setText(args.getString(ARG_DB_STAT));
        //This is the only way I found to update the text
        //But tv_db_stat need to be static to keep the reference
        //When I update the arguments from the activity
        //Of course, I get a warning about a context class being static

        return fragment;
    }
```

As I said in the comments, the only way that the TextView is updated is keeping it as static, as it needs to be updated after returning to main activity from a second activity. If I remove the .setText() from here and let it only in onCreate or onViewCreated, the text do not update. If I don't make it static, I have (as you should expect) a NPE.

(**EDIT**) I tried to use a container in my XML hardcoded layout, but, as you have guess, the fragment.replace.commit just overlap the widgets...

This works "ok", but I don't like the possibility of a memory leak, I have try almost all advice over there, but non of them refresh my TextView but this.

in the activity I'm just doing this:

```
    Stored_Fragment sf = new Stored_Fragment();
    sf.newInstance(DB_STAT);
```

So, what do you thing shall be a better alternative to this "solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind,  I found a turn around using onResume that, I guess, is called after the newInstance method.  I Just move the setText to onResume where it does not need to be static.  Still testing, but I could clean my code by now.